# How to return new variable after some promise process?

Tags: javascript

```
getCategory().then((res) => {
  let itemList = res;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    for(let i=0; i < res.length; i++ ) {
      getItems(res[i].url).then((itempage) => {
        const $ = itempage;
        const pagination = $('.pagination .page').toArray().length;
        itemList[i].total_page = pagination;
      });
    }
    resolve(itemList);
  });
}).then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
});
```

Above is my code. First of all, I assign `res` to a new variable called `itemList` which is an object array.
Then I do some functions with promise and try to add new data to `itemList`.

However, when the `console.log(res)` still prints out original `itemList`.

I know this may caused by promise function but how to fix it?

Comment: What is the expected output? It's not clear from your code at all.

Comment: I think the logic of your program needs revisiting. 1st you seem to have promise inside promise. And they are async in nature meaning they do not have a return value as you expect it. You need to provide callbacks and work with them. Maybe if you explain your exact business case it will be easier to get help.

Comment: try resolving itemList after this line itemList[i].total_page = pagination;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead

```
getCategory().then(itemList => {
  return Promise.all([itemList, Promise.all(itemList.map(x => getItems(x.url)))]);
}).then(([itemList, items]) => {
  items.forEach(($, i) => {
    itemList[i].total_page = $('.pagination .page').toArray().length;
  });
  return itemList;
}).then(console.log);
```

I think that will get you there (i.e. with the side-effected `itemList`). Note that this will fail if any of your `getItems` calls fails.

This is actually a common problem with Promises: you want to use the results asynchronously (as if you had a choice) but combine that with the original results. So here I've used `Promise.all` to resolve an array of Promises of the `getItems` calls which turns that into a single Promise that awaits all of the results. Then I put that in an array with the `itemList` and then call `Promise.all` on that and return that Promise. Then next `.then` in the chain gets an array with two arrays inside: the original `itemList` and the array of the now-resolved calls to `getItems`. At this point the `forEach` executes the side effects, and we just return the now updated `itemList`.

Comment: wow, this really solved my problem.Appreciated! i will try to understand this.

Comment: @Dreams I updated with an explanation, let me know if you have other questions. If this worked for you please consider accepting.